# laptop hibernation mode, sql express and data corruption

Tags: sql-server

We recently got a corruption problem (error 824) from a database hosted in sql server express 2005 on a latop configured to use hibernation (windows xp).  I do not have access to this laptop yet to perform disk tests.

Is there any known problems using hibernation mode and sql server express on laptops?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you hit the KB at microsoft?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen it mentioned rarely (not being able to create new connections after coming out of hibernation, I think it was).

I have a similar setup, although I'm now using the 2008 version, and I routinely (every single day, basically) send my machine to hibernation mode at the end of the day, and have not seen a similar problem.

I'd start with the event log (system and application) and see if you notice anything related to file or IO errors at the time you sent it to hibernate, or when SQL server was trying to start.